# Sort a LINQ grouped query based on the group

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a problem with these simple classes:

```
public class Thread
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public DateTime Posted { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like a LINQ query that will return all Threads, sorted in latest post order. Assuming an Entity Framework DbContext with `Threads` and `Posts`, how to write it? Grouping is simple:

```
from t in Threads
group t.Posts by t into tg
select tg.Key;
```

But how to sort the Threads based on the latest `Post.Posted`?

**Edit - Solution based on Jons answer:**

```
from t in Threads
from p in t.Posts
group p by t into tg
orderby tg.Max(p => p.Posted) descending 
select tg.Key
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
from t in Threads
group t.Posts by t into tg
orderby tg.Max(post => post.Posted) // Order by the latest post per thread
select tg.Key;
```

Obviously use `descending` if you want the threads ordered with the mostly-recently-posted thread first.

Comment: Thank you very much! I made it work by adding a "from p in t.Posts" then grouping and ordering by that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
var orderedThread1 = from t in threads
                     from p in t.Posts
                     orderby p.Posted ascending 
                     select t;

var orderedThread2 = from t in threads
                     group t.Posts by t
                     into tp
                     orderby tp.Max(posts => posts.Max(p => p.Posted))
                     select tp.Key;
```